# Отображение виджетов в tkinter: скрыть и вернуть обратно

Tags: python, функции, tkinter

Мне нужно завершать функцию и удалять объекты `button` и `Label` после начала выполнения другой функции.Вот эта функция:

```
def child():
     btn = Button(root, text="Подтвердить",  background="#708090",padx="20", pady="8",
                 font="16")
     o = Entry(root)
     def sum_back():
       if int(o.get()) <= s:
           ost=s-o

     text = Label(root, text="Сумма к оплате: %s" % (s))
     text1 = Label(root, text= "Вы оплачиваете : %s" % (o))
     text2 = Label(root, text = "Осталось оплатить: %s" %(ost))

     text.pack()
     text1.pack()
     o.pack()

     text2.pack()

     btn.pack()
     root.grab_set()
     root.focus_set()
```

Далее идет другая функция. Так вот , мне нужно, что бы после нажатия на n ную кнопку функция "скрывала" кнопки и лейблы. А после повторного вызывания функции снова "возвращала".

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to delete Tkinter widgets from a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12364981/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно при помощи компоновщика `.grid()` добавлять объект и временно удалять  при помощи `.grid_remove()`
Пример:

```
import tkinter


def func():
        label_visible_false.grid()
        button_visible_false.grid()
        label_visible_true.grid_remove()
        button_visible_true.grid_remove()


def visible_true():
        label_visible_false.grid_remove()
        button_visible_false.grid_remove()
        label_visible_true.grid()
        button_visible_true.grid()


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
label_visible_true = tkinter.Label(root, text='Не скрытый текст')
label_visible_true.grid()

button_visible_true = tkinter.Button(root, text='Не скрытая кнопка', command=func)
button_visible_true.grid()

label_visible_false = tkinter.Label(root, text='Скрытый текст')

button_visible_false = tkinter.Button(root, text='Скрытая кнопка', command=visible_true)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Так же это можно сделать с  `pack()` при помощи функции `pack_forget()`
Пример c `pack()`:

```
import tkinter


def func():
        label_visible_false.pack()
        button_visible_false.pack()
        label_visible_true.pack_forget()
        button_visible_true.pack_forget()


def visible_true():
        label_visible_false.pack_forget()
        button_visible_false.pack_forget()
        label_visible_true.pack()
        button_visible_true.pack()


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
label_visible_true = tkinter.Label(root, text='Не скрытый текст')
label_visible_true.pack()

button_visible_true = tkinter.Button(root, text='Не скрытая кнопка', command=func)
button_visible_true.pack()

label_visible_false = tkinter.Label(root, text='Скрытый текст')

button_visible_false = tkinter.Button(root, text='Скрытая кнопка', command=visible_true)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Так же можно и с `place()` при помощи того же `place_forget()`

```
import tkinter


def func():
        label_visible_false.place(x=0, y=50)
        button_visible_false.place(x=0, y=100)
        label_visible_true.place_forget()
        button_visible_true.place_forget()


def visible_true():
        label_visible_false.place_forget()
        button_visible_false.place_forget()
        label_visible_true.place(x=0, y=50)
        button_visible_true.place(x=0, y=100)


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
label_visible_true = tkinter.Label(root, text='Не скрытый текст')
label_visible_true.place(x=0, y=50)

button_visible_true = tkinter.Button(root, text='Не скрытая кнопка', command=func)
button_visible_true.place(x=0, y=100)

label_visible_false = tkinter.Label(root, text='Скрытый текст')

button_visible_false = tkinter.Button(root, text='Скрытая кнопка', command=visible_true)

root.mainloop()
```