# Не работает упаковщик grid_remove()

Tags: python, tkinter

я думаю, что это из-за того что упаковщик находется в функции и должен скрывать кнопки, которые состоят в других функциях. Помогите пожалуйста мне это исправить

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()

def name1():
    if but1['text']=='Запад':
        lab['text']='West'

def name2():
    if but2['text']=='Восток':
        lab['text']='East'

def name3():
    if but3['text']=='Север':
        lab['text']='North'        

def name4():
    if but4['text']=='Юг':
        lab['text']='Sourth'

def name():
    if but['text']=='Скрыть':
        far.grid_remove()
        but['text'] ='Показать'

    else:
        but['text'] ='Скрыть'
        far.pack()


but=Button(root,text="Скрыть",height=1,width=7,command=name)
but.pack()

far=Frame(root)
far.pack()


but3=Button(far,text="Север",height=1,width=5,command=name3)
but3.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)


but4=Button(far,text="Юг",height=1,width=5,command=name4)
but4.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)


but1=Button(far,text="Запад",height=1,width=5,command=name1)
but1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

lab=Label(far,text='',height=1,width=5)
lab.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)

but2=Button(far,text="Восток",height=1,width=5,command=name2)
but2.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5,pady=5)
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Отображение виджетов в tkinter: скрыть и вернуть обратно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/792010/255866)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь убрать виджет far, который упакован упаковщиком pack, методом `.grid_remove()`(упаковщик grid). Для упаковщика pack есть своя функция `.pack_forget()`.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло

Answer (score 0):

дело в том что в используемой вами ГУИ есть три метода моделирования: pack, grid, place [упаковщики](https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5_Tkinter_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_Python#%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8). разница между ними в том, что для place нужно самому указывать координаты в пикселях (начальную и конечную точку расколожения каждого элемента); grid - создаёт ГУИ на основе таблицы, как в экселе, т.е. он создаёт условную таблицу для себя и не видимую для остальных, размеры каждых элементов являются условными в зависимости от передаваемых... долго рассказывать все зависимости...; и pack - самый простой и распространённый упаковщик. по умолчанию, он использует заложенную длину (но её легко изменить добавив такой параметр width) каждого элемента. так же стоит отметить, что он по умолчанию (если не используется Frame) все элементы размещаются один под другим...
это я всё к тому, что существует не гласное правило самой библиотеки: "нельзя в одном файле программы упаковывать все элементы разными упаковщиками, нужно использовать только один из них". скажу по секрету, что можно только когда используешь модульную структуру программы:).
а теперь отвечаю на вопрос, для того чтоб "забыть" какой либо элемент, используются связка (так написанно в документации, но это не правило использовать) forget и destroy. forget - для упаковщика (pack_forget, grid_forget), destroy - для компилятора (очистить память)

```
frame_general.pack_forget()
frame_general.destroy()
```

переведите весь Ваш код исключительно для одного упаковщика. к примеру, Вы начинали использовать в самом начале pack, так пусть везде будет pack

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже перевёл все на один упаковщик.