# Управление видимостью объектов в окне при использовании tkinter в Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Начинаю осваивать Python. Хочу сделать игру, где фигуры должны то появляться в окне, то скрываться. В Delphi я делал это с лёгкостью, меняя свойство объекта visible(true|false). Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли такая возможность в tkinter? Или придется плясать с бубном? А может использовать другую библиотеку?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/791876/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-tkinter-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE Возможно подойдет?

Comment: https://www.rupython.com/tkinter-x4-1341.html

Comment: можно удалять объект и снова его делать

Comment: Смотря что за фигуры, и как вы их размещаете.

Answer (score 1):

pack_forget() метод для сокрытия виджетов Tkinter размещённых по методу pack()
grid_forget() метод для сокрытия виджетов Tkinter размещённых по методу grid()
place_forget() метод для сокрытия виджетов Tkinter размещённых по методу place()

чтобы их сделать видимыми нужно снова применить паковщик, который вы использовали, то есть: pack, grid, place.

Надеюсь объяснил нормально. Вроде самый не костыльный способ